Why my customized snippets can't take effect?
webapi-vim has been installed in bundle:
cd  ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/mattn/webapi-vim
ls  
emmet-vim  ultisnips  vim-snippets  webapi-vim

Add g:user_emmet_settings in .vimrc:
let g:user_emmet_settings = webapi#json#decode(join(readfile(expand('/home/debian/.vim/bundle/emmet-vim/snippets.json')), "\n"))

Edit the snippets.json:
cat  /home/debian/.vim/bundle/emmet-vim/snippets.json
{
    "html": {
        "abbreviations": {
            "hello": "testing abbreviation"
        }
    }
}

hello expand into <hello></hello>, instead of testing abbreviation,when edit html file.How to fix it?

Read the plugin's documentation and use its issue tracker. Also Vim has had :help json_decode() for a while so that "web-api" thing seems largely useless. Moreover, you are already using another snippet expansion plugin so why make things more complicated than they already are by adding a second one… with a different syntax?
